# Get all value of the page buttons by class in jQuery and save in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having Issue getting value of the button. I have the list of button in a table which have `value()` attribute. I am trying to get that values and save in array.But this code is not working.

**HTML**

```
<input class="btn send btn-warning" style="float: right;  height: 32px; margin-top: 5px;width: 10%" id="sendButton" value="All" name="sendButton" type="button">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td>123</td>
            <td>J545</td>
            <td>
                <label class="GetTheScanId">3213156454</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td>123</td>
            <td>J545</td>
            <td>
                <label class="GetTheScanId">1234</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>  
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#sendButton').click(function () {
    debugger;
    var array = [];
    $('.table tbody tr').each(function () {
        var values = [];
        $(this).find(".GetTheScanId").each(function () {
            alert(this.val());
            values.push(this.val());
        });
        array.push(values);
    });
    alert(array);
});
```

Comment: [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) is used for input elements. Use `$(this).text()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from this expression `this.val()`, since `val()` is a jQuery function and you couldn't call it on DOM object.

Also note that the `label` doesn't have a value so you should use `.text()` instead of `.val()` to get the `label` text :

```
$(this).text()
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#sendButton').click(function() {
  debugger;
  var array = [];
  $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var values = [];
    $(this).find(".GetTheScanId").each(function() {
      alert( $(this).text() );
      values.push( $(this).text() );
    });
    array.push(values);
  });
  alert(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="btn send btn-warning" style="float: right;  height: 32px; margin-top: 5px;width: 10%" id="sendButton" value="All" name="sendButton" type="button">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">

  <tbody>
    <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
      <td>123</td>
      <td>J545</td>
      <td>
        <label class="GetTheScanId">3213156454</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
      <td>123</td>
      <td>J545</td>
      <td>
        <label class="GetTheScanId">1234</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Getting error Uncaught TypeError: this.val is not a function on $(this).val()

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` to jQ constructor and then call `.val()` on it.

```
this.val(); // Wrong! .val() is not defined!
$(this).val(); // Correct
```

Comment: Getting error Uncaught TypeError: this.val is not a function on $(this).val()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` method like following. And also you need to use `text()` instead of `val()` for getting text.

```js
$('#sendButton').click(function () {
    var array = $('.table tbody tr .GetTheScanId').map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    
    console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn send btn-warning" style="float: right;  height: 32px; margin-top: 5px;width: 10%" id="sendButton" value="All" name="sendButton" type="button">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">         <tbody>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td>123</td>
            <td>J545</td>
            <td>
                <label class="GetTheScanId">3213156454</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td>123</td>
            <td>J545</td>
            <td>
                <label class="GetTheScanId">1234</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>  
</table>
```